# Can I inject JS into a chrome dev tools window with an extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to write a Chrome Extension that lets me inject JS into the dev tools window.

The dev tools window has a scheme of "devtools://" which is not a valid scheme for a content script url "match" in the manifest.json.

Is this possible another way?

Comment: No, it's intentionally forbidden. For a personal unpacked extension try [this workaround](/q/19042857).